# Squish - no verification while recording

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, bdd, squish

At times when right clicking and hitting "Record Missing Steps in Scenario", I am able to get the AUT open, the Squish Control Bar open, and all buttons on the control bar are active (except Pause of course). However, when I go to try to use Verify with Properties for a step, the control bar buttons disable for a second, then re-enable, and I'm not able to pick any properties.

This happens whether the scenario is among other scenarios in a feature file, or on its own. There is no existing code in the steps.js, or if there is, it is commented out so that new code can be auto-generated. I doubt it matters, but I'm trying to record a "When" step.

Any thoughts and ideas appreciated! I have not contacted support yet as I am working on a bigger issue with them.

---Update---
This seems to occur when I try to modify a 'given', 'when', or 'then' case that's already recorded, by changing the wording in order to record a new case. Or, when I comment the existing case out to auto-generate the new steps that are recorded. Is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: Please contact the vendor of froglogic Squish for help with such things which are probably issues in Squish itself. Please be sure to provide any information helpful for reproducing this, and the support information ZIP file (Help > Collect Support Information...) collected after reproducing the problem once.

Comment: @frog.ca - I think I've described the repro to the best of my abilities, as it seems to occur randomly. Due to the time zone difference its faster to post here than to contact the company. Thanks!